# SQL best practice from multiple table links

Tags: mysql, database-design

I wasnt sure how best to word this title, or even explain the problem but here goes...

I am designing an SQL database with several tables that can be linked together.
i.e.

```
TABLE a ID1 CAN BE JOINED TO TABLE b ID1
TABLE b ID2 CAN BE JOINED TO TABLE c ID1
TABLE d ID1 CAN BE JOINED TO TABLE a ID5
```

etc.

Basically any row in any table can be linked to any other row in any table (including itself)

i was going to create a single "Connections" table with the following columns...

```
Table 1 Name VARCHAR()
Table 1 ID   INT()
Table 2 Name VARCHAR()
Table 2 ID   INT()
```

Acting as a many to many joining table but with columns for the table as well as ID of each side of the connection. I get the feeling this isn't best practise though. Any thoughts?
I cant believe i need to create an individual table for each permutation of connection!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is common, opposing the normalized model to the denormalized model.

To implement a meta-model (one table to store all relations) most commonly has the following issues:

- Slower requests in case of 0..n relations (at least)
- No native management of relational constraints (on cascade...)
- Needs an additional applicative layer to parse the relations

Then if you don't mind it, your solution is fine.

Cheers,
S.

Comment: So basically there is no perfect solution here? but this is the bet of the bunch? (taking your limitations into account)

Comment: To use the native RDBMS functionalities are in my opinion the best solution (this is already 30 years the world is working on it :-)). Normalize your system and, when necessary, denormalize it.